# Is it possible to skip nodes in D3.js tree?

Tags: d3.js

I am just curious is it possible to skip some nodes in tree and connect for example root node with last node in tree?

Something like this:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/EFp4HvN.png]

and if it possible maybe you know where I could find some examples? Or maybe using tree is not an option in such cases?

Any comments would be very helpful,

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the Collapsible Tree examples out there, and the Data Structure that they use is a tree scruture, which is basically parent -> children[], thus not being able to provide such funcionality.

But it doesn't mean that you cannot implement the same tree using a different structure, like a graph structure, for example. Just keep in mind that you will have to treat some corner cases (eg.: children that are connected to other children across parents), so the tree representation maybe could not be the best for your use case.

You should consider analyzing your use case, then choosing which graph best suits your needs.